# Sidekiq keeps yelling at CSRF protection, but the route is mounted inside Rails.application.routes.draw

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6.0.3.5 API, and i'm NOT using Devise for authentication.
When I try to access sidekiq UI, it yells:

```rb
Sidekiq::Web needs a valid Rack session for CSRF protection. If this is a Rails app, make sure you mount Sidekiq::Web *inside* your application routes: Rails.application.routes.draw do mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq" .... end
```

But actually my routes are exactly like that:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
     ...
    end
  end
end
```

I've protected the route with user/pass in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` like that:

```rb
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'
Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|  
  Rack::Utils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(user), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_USER"])) &
    Rack::Utils.secure_compare(::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password), ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(ENV["SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD"]))
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solution given by Github user "gagalago" here. It worked for me!

Have this in your **config/routes.rb** file:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

# Configure Sidekiq-specific session middleware
Sidekiq::Web.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
Sidekiq::Web.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: "_interslice_session"

Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
  # ...
end
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4850#issuecomment-810880012

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.  This should be the suggested answer to add Sidekiq Web support to Rails api-only applications when updating to the latest sidekiq version.

Comment: Also a solution: Sidekiq::Web.use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: 'SecretKey'

Answer (score 7):

You are using Rails in API mode, where it does not provide a session so you can't mount other Rack apps which depend on a session. Documented here:

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#using-session-middlewares

Comment: Dunno why but it worked just by downgrading sidekiq to 6.1.3. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at the changelog for v6.2.0?

Comment: Downgrading shouldn't be a solution. Please check my answer and see if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

For bare Rack apps:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: "your_SECURE_key", same_site: true, max_age: 86400
run Sidekiq::Web
```

More info: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/main/Changes.md#620